# Change package.json through Vercel?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, compilation, vercel

I'm trying to deploy my portfolio with Vercel but I have an error at deployment time:

`src/components/header/ChangeLanguage.vue(12,25): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'vue-i18n'. '/vercel/path0/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.esm-bundler.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. There are types at '/vercel/path0/node_modules/vue-i18n/dist/vue-i18n.d.ts', but this result could not be resolved when respecting package.json "exports". The 'vue-i18n' library may need to update its package.json or typings.`

I also had this problem locally but I fixed it by adding "types":"./dist/vue-i18n.d.ts" in `node_modules/vue-i18n/package.json` file

However, I can't modify this same file through Vercel because I haven't control over this. What's the solution ?

Thanks in advance